# NSString as argument between multiple classes

Tags: objective-c

I am sending `NSStrings` many times, between classes, and i think i am loosing them.

lets say i have : `classA ,classB, classC`

`classA` having instance of `classB`(allocated) and he is calling function in classB,
the function in B:

```
-(NSMutableData*)setProtocolDataForString:(NSString*)data WithCommand:(int)comm
{ //here i can see and log the string 'data', but i am sending him to classC from here
  [classCInstance send:data];
}
```

`classA` call that function with : `..setProtocolDataForString:@"ran"];`

As i wrote inside, i can see that classB get the string,but after he pass him to another classC ,i think it is being lost.
How exactly functions save/retain the value of `NS` arguments they get ?
How would i do it right so this string can be passed between infinite classes and not freed?

**dont know if its important,but classA/B dont use ARC, but classC does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class `B` needs to have it's own copy of the string it is passing on to class `C`. Since `NSString` instances are considered to be value objects you do not simply retain a string, but create a copy instead.

`NSString newString = [aString copy];` in this scenario `aString` can safely be released since you already have a copy with its very own retain count which is not going to be released.

Don't forget to release / auto-release your copy. This is not automatically done for you. If you forget this, your application will leak memory.

The following code should work for you:

```
[classCInstance send:[[data copy] autorelease]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Either allocate or retain **NSString** object before pass it to class method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to retain the string because class A and B are not ARC enabled.

```
-(NSMutableData*)setProtocolDataForString:(NSString*)data WithCommand:(int)comm
{ //here I can see and log the string 'data', but I am sending him to classC from here
   [data retain];
  [classCInstance send:data];
}
```